# Jupyter notebook interface different

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter

I am following a video lecture series on YT to learn pandas. The jupyter notebook interface is different on my pc and in the tutorial.

This is the interface in the tutorial:

[Original Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDv7c.png)

This is the interface that I see:

[My interface:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkinA.png)

As it is clearly seen, the interface in tutorial is compact compared to mine. It also has In and Out symbols before every code line which is missing from my interface. As a result I don't see output to the commands when I run the code. Plz help.

Comment: Seems like you're using JupyterLab, while the video is using Jupyter Notebook. They are just different tools, (checkout both at the Project Jupyter homepage](https://jupyter.org/)

Answer (score 5):

Like said in another answer, this is **not necessarily a problem** - the new interface was launched with Notebook version 7.0.0 (which you are pprobably on). This new interface is known as RetroLab and comes with an updated appearance similar to JupyterLab.

Now, if you want to **go back to the traditional version** out of preference (like I did), here's how to:

If you're running a 7.x.x version and want to downgrade, you can do so using pip:

`pip install notebook==6.4.4`

This will install the last version of Jupyter Notebook before 7.0.0, which still uses the classic interface.

Now you can launch Jupyter Notebook as you usually would, and it should use the classic interface.

Comment: For more current context for this answer and other answers & comments about JupyterLab, it is suggested to see about NbClassic vs. Notebook 7(and  versions beyond) described [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-notebook-6-5-0-release-candidate-4c229c6dab55) and JupyterLab version 4 described [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-4-0-is-here-388d05e03442).

Comment: The 'Retrolab' branding you point out isn't exactly correct as stated in your answer. For a time, the interface was RetroLab, but that has now  been integrated into Notebook v7 (and beyond) to be the main version of the document-centric offering built off JupyterLab components, see [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/retrolab#%EF%B8%8F-retrolab-and-notebook-v7-%EF%B8%8F).

Comment: Fresh post [Announcing Jupyter Notebook 7](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf). "**A Familiar Document-Oriented Experience** Starting with what does not change, Notebook 7 still focuses on the document-centric user experience that made the classic IPython and Jupyter Notebook application so popular." It covers the why of NbClassic, too: "...some existing users might need a medium-term option for backward-compatibility with Notebook 6 using NbClassic, which delivers the same user experience and can be run on the same server as JupyterLab and Notebook 7."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is nothing to be concerned about. The tutor in the video is using the old school [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/#:%7E:text=Jupyter%20Notebook%3A%20The%20Classic%20Notebook%20Interface), which is the go-to editor because

1. It's the original Jupyter Notebook software.
2. Easy to set up.

However, the one you are using is called [JupyterLab](https://jupyter.org/#:%7E:text=JupyterLab%3A%20A%20Next%2DGeneration%20Notebook%20Interface), which also is quite popular, and as you can already tell, is more user-friendly.

The same project (Jupyter) developed these two open source tools and both of them have good support for IPython, and have active communities. The same backend is used and the keyboard shortcuts are also the same.

In short, they are just different versions of the same software, and you can do everything the tutor is doing on your PC, using the software you showed (JupyterLab).

If you are looking for an alternative UI with more control, I suggest you use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It has excellent support for Jupyter Notebooks and can be customized to suit your needs with numerous extensions.