# What is this version of Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, version

i'm trying to install jupyter notebook, it's pretty easy, but the version or "type" after i pip install jupyter notebook is really different with others.
[This is different UI of Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7ox2.png)
[It can't automatically close the bracket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcdoa.png)

Now this is the version that i want to use and been using before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzaQu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtpW0.png)

Please help me solve this, my version of Jupyter notebook is 7.0.2. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook interface different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363525/jupyter-notebook-interface-different)